# Aggregating strings using tostring and counting them in r

Tags: r, dplyr

I have following dataframe got after applying dplyr code

```
Final_df<- df   %>%
    group_by(clientID,month) %>%
    summarise(test=toString(Sector)) %>%
    as.data.frame()
```

Which gives me following output

```
  ClientID       month          test
   ASD            Sep       Auto,Auto,Finance
   DFG            Oct       Finance,Auto,Oil
```

How I want is to count sectors as well

```
  ClientID       month          test
   ASD            Sep      Auto:2,Finance:1
   DFG            Oct      Finance:1,Auto:1,Oil:1
```

How can I achieve it with dplyr?

Comment: Are you interested only in `dplyr` solution or a base R approach would do as well ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try

```
df %>% 
    group_by(client_id, month, Sector) %>%
    tally() %>%
    group_by(client_id, month) %>%
    summarise(test = toString(paste(Sector, n, sep=":")))
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .N, .(ClientID, month, Sector)
    ][, .(test = toString(paste(Sector, N, sep=":"))) , .(ClientID, month)]
```

---

If we need a `base R`

```
aggregate(newCol~ClientID + month, transform(aggregate(n~., 
    transform(df, n = 1), sum), newCol = paste(Sector, n, sep=":")), toString)
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(ClientID = rep(c("ASD.", "DFG."), each = 5),
         month = rep(c("Sep", "Oct" ) , c(3,2)),
         Sector = c("Auto", "Auto", "Finance", "Finance", "Finance", 
         "Auto", "Finance", "Finance", "Oil", "Oil"),
        stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Comment: can we find what is the change from sep to oct month for his investments in different sectors. Like is sep client was holding 2 instruments from Auto sector but in Oct he has reduced to 1 like wise. Or he has added any new sector which was not present in Sepember month.

Comment: Can we achieve above in the same dplyr pipe ?

Answer (score 4):

Here's a similar but slightly different solution to the one by @akrun:

```
count(df, ClientID, month, Sector) %>% 
  summarise(test = toString(paste(Sector, n, sep=":")))
#Source: local data frame [4 x 3]
#Groups: ClientID [?]
#
#  ClientID month              test
#     <chr> <chr>             <chr>
#1     ASD.   Oct         Finance:2
#2     ASD.   Sep Auto:2, Finance:1
#3     DFG.   Oct             Oil:2
#4     DFG.   Sep Auto:1, Finance:2
```

In this case, `count` does the same as `group_by` + `tally` and you don't need another `group_by` since the `count` removes the outer most grouping variable (`Sector`) automagically.